# Ebean not updating booleans if they are false

Tags: java, sql, playframework, ebean

Today I came up with very strange issue using **Ebean** in *Play Framework*. I have multiple models with some boolean properties.

If I am saving the entity initially, everything works fine. But, when I edit such entity and change boolean value from **true to false**, such property is not saved. I investigated called `SQL UPDATE` and desired property is simply missing in `UPDATE`. Anyway, If I edit the same entity and change the same boolean property from **false to true**, update works just fine.

It looks like **Ebean** is handling false booleans like if it was null value and so it is not considering such property in UPDATE.

I am using java version of Play 2.4.6 with non-default Ebean version 4.7.1. (I was forced to use non-default version of Ebean because of bug https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/309)

Comment: After a lot of investigation it seems that the issue is more related to Play than to Ebean. If I load the entity from database, change the boolean value and update directly the same instance of entity, everything is working. Once the entity is loaded through Form binding, Ebean does not update booleans. Maybe it is related to play-enhancer?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I figured that out. Not an Ebean issue. It is "by design" behavior of Play framework and HTTP processing.

Problem is in binding of booleans from HTML forms. When I tick the checkbox of a form, I get value back from the request (something like *id_of_checkbox = true*). When I do not tick a checkbox, nothing gets back in the request and so the Entity property is not set. As a result of this, Ebean thinks that property has not changed and so it is not necessary to include such property in SQL statement, hence it is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common problem not only in Play but also in other frameworks and/or languages.

Fortunately there's simple trick, which resolves it in all cases, just in HTML code place the hidden input with the `name` attribute identical as your checkbox and some value representing false right before the checkbox, so your code finally should look like:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="agreeBox" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="agreeBox" id="agreeBox"/>
    <label for="agreeBox">Do you agree?</label>
</div>
```

Of course if you plan many checkboxes in your view it will be easier to create [**custom tag**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Tags-(they-are-just-functions-right?)), which will append hidden field to each checkbox.

**IMPORTANT EDIT FOR Play!**

In Play situation is opposite than I suspected - if there are fields with the same name only **first** will be used, that means that using the trick requires to place the `hidden` input **AFTER** the checkbox so ready to use HTML should look like:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agreeBox" id="agreeBox"/>
    <label for="agreeBox">Do you agree?</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="agreeBox" value="0" />
</div>
```